# Auto-layout with different combinations of elements

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UITableViewCell with a few different icons that can be shown in different combinations. Here is an example:

[image]

In this case, there are 4 different combinations:

1. all 3 elements are showing on screen (as shown in image) -> in this case, all the elements are equally spaced from each other
2. two out of the 3 elements are showing -> in this case, the two element should occupy the space more elegantly, so that contentView to firstIcon, firstIcon to secondIcon, and secondIcon and bottom of contentView should all be equally spaced
3. one of the 3 elements are showing -> in this case, the one element should be centered on screen
4. none of the elements are showing

I'm trying to figure out how to layout the constraints in this case, ideally without having to do this in code with removing and adding all these constraints at run-time while a tableview is scrolling, which might make the scrolling jerky.

Is there a way I can get this to work at design-time? Perhaps by putting some constraint to vertically center each image as much as possible, and only have it resist if there are other elements. The missing elements could be 'hidden' or removed from the contentView altogether (whichever works best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your design-time solution will work. There aren't constraints you can specify like that - hidden views participate in layout, and if you're removing views, then you're removing constraints.

Don't assume that constraint updating will give you a performance problem - do it the simplest way first, then measure.

In this case the simplest way is probably to use a container view to hold your three icons. This can be pinned to the top and bottom of the cell, and at the correct distance from the right edge. These constraints won't change.

All three image views can be added to this container. Horizontally, they don't need constraints - they can default to zero on the x axis and will have an intrinsic width.

Depending on the cell content, you'd then set each image view to visible or not, remove the constraints on the container view and then add the new ones to give vertical position. The simplest set of constraints would be using multipliers on the container view's bottom. You'd constrain the center Y of each visible image view to the appropriate multiplier - if there was only one visible, multiplier 0.5, if there were two, 0.33 and 0.66, and for all three, 0.25, 0.5 and 0.75.

This isn't a complex set of constraints and I'd be surprised if it caused scrolling problems.

Comment: Dangit - that's pretty much verbatim what I had just worked out to suggest ... Although I was working on generalizing it to loop & add constraints based on number of images.

Comment: Sounds very efficient. But I'm confused about a couple of things: does the container view shrink in height depending on the number of elements? Or does it stay the same, vertically centered in the content view, and only the elements within it are changed? Also, when you say the image view should be contained with a multiplier; what is it being constrained to? The adjacent image, or the container view?

Comment: @mc01 the loop is what I do and it's pretty straightforward, but I typed this answer on my phone so I try to avoid code...

Comment: The container view stays the same size (the full height of the cell). Each image is constrained relative to the container's height.

Comment: How do you constrain the centerY of an image to the height of it's superview? When I try this: `NSLayoutConstraint *att1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.firstIcon attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.iconContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0.5 constant:0];`  but it gives me an error "[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Invalid pairing of layout attributes"

Comment: You pin to the bottom of the container, not the height.